# difference between loadData() and loadDataWithBaseURL() in WebView class.....?

Tags: webview, loaddata

can anybody tell me the difference between loadData() and loadDataWithBaseURL() in WebView class.

when i used `web.loadDataWithBaseURL("",html, mimetype, encoding,"");` in my program , where html is the string that contains hard coded html tags, its displaying just like as html page
where as when i used loadData(html,mimetype,encoding) in my code the application is closing.

i read the API but could not understand it.....
so please help me...

Thanks in Advance

Ash

Answer (score 8):

In case someone comes across this, WebView.loadData seems to be broken:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1733#c23

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3552

Variants of the solution suggested in the OP's question seems to be the workaround.  I figure nulls are cheaper than "", so I used this:

```
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,html, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

Comment: thanks this solved my problem!  loadData works on Android 3.0 platforms, but breaks on 2.2+ platforms